# Permission Denial: receiving Intent

Tags: android, broadcast-receiver, permissions

Цель - после перезагрузки запускать Alarm, но он не запускается.

System Process выдаёт вот это

```
10-24 13:16:04.460 477-487/system_process W/BroadcastQueue: Permission Denial: receiving Intent { act=android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED flg=0x10 (has extras) } to com.xxxx.yyyy.project/.StartAtBoot requires android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED due to sender null (uid 1000)
```

Manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.RECEIVE_BOOT_COMPLETED" />
    <receiver android:name=".StartAtBoot" android:enabled="true" android:exported="true"  >
        <intent-filter >
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED" />
        </intent-filter>
    </receiver>
```

StartAtBoot

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

   AlarmManager am=
            (AlarmManager)context.getSystemService(Context.ALARM_SERVICE);
    if("android.intent.action.BOOT_COMPLETED".equalsIgnoreCase(intent.getAction())){
        Intent i= new Intent(context, Receiver.class);
        PendingIntent pIntent2 = PendingIntent.getBroadcast(context, 0, i, 0);
      am.setRepeating(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, System.currentTimeMillis() + 10000, 10800000, pIntent2);
      System.out.println("BOOT_COMPLETED WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
    }


}
```

Receiver

```
public void onReceive(Context ctx, Intent intent) {
System.out.println("BOOT_COMPLETED WORKS!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!!");
}
```

Comment: На какой строчке. Полный стек трейс

Comment: Полный стек трейс?

Comment: Ну да, предоставьте полный лог. Либо скиньте строчку на которой ошибка происходит

Comment: Могу только полный лог System Process скинуть, но он ничего не даст, там к ребуту одна строчка относиться, которую я скинул, сама активити после ребута не запущена, поэтому ошибок от туда нету.

Comment: У вас 6 версия оси так себя ведёт? Что если это разрешение надо в рантайме прописать?

Comment: разрешение прям так перед объявлением ресивера стоит?